# Delete ALL cookies in Android Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, delete, cookies

Running Chrome 60.0.3112.116 on Android 7.1.1 I tried to remove *all* cookies from the browser using the `Clear Data` button provided in `Advanced` tab of Chrome's Privacy Settings (selected `All Time` to make sure to delete all stored cookies).

However, the cookies section in the `Advanced` tab showed about 30 cookies before clicking on `Clear Data` and I had 23 left after deleting the cookies. Since some cookies can be deleted while the browser closes I quit Chrome and went back to `Settings`, giving me the same 23 cookies left.

I am a bit surprised about that fact since I thought clearing all data actually means that all stored data (including all cookies) is being removed, which in fact obviously does not seem to be true.

Since I am using Google News App and allowed to open web content inside the GMail App I think those 23 left cookies might come from those two apps since those apps should be based upon the system-built-in version of Chrome, but I am not sure and unable to proof this assumption.

In order to make sure that this is not a somehow other related problem, I went to `Apps` of `Android Settings` and cleared Chrome's cache which does not result in any changes. However, `Clear All Data` via the `Manage Space` option does delete the cookies hence resetting Chrome to its initial state.

Is there any way to really remove all cookies from Chrome without resetting Chrome via `Android Settings` as described above? Do you have any suggestions where those 'additional' cookies come from?